# Forcing https causes all folders to redirect

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, apache2

I have quite a large site that consists of some regular web pages in the root and a lot of Joomla sites in folders.

So it looks a little like this:

```
- index.php (root)
- about.php (root)
- product.php (root)
/joomlasite1
/joomlasite2
/joomlasite3
```

I asked my web host to help put a redirect in the `.htaccess` to force https and www. But when they did this every Joomla site redirected to the root so I had to remove it.

This is the rule they put in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can someone suggest the best way to do this? Am I going to have to put a redirect in the root and also one in every Joomla site folder?

Comment: Are those Joomla sites on different domains?    What code got put in that wasn't working?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller they are all on the same domain. So mydomain.co.uk is the root and the Joomla sites are in mydomain.co.uk/joomlasite1 for example. I foolishly didn't save the code that the host put in but I will update the question with it if I find it.

Comment: If these are all on the same domain then what exactly do you want to force to HTTPS and what should stay on HTTP? You would normally expect to force HTTPS across the entire domain.

Comment: @MrWhite Sorry I should have been clearer. I want to force everything to www. and HTTPS. So the root site and all joomla sites that are in folders.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - I think I misread your question. However, do you have additional `.htaccess` files in these `/joomlasite` subdirectories? I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite I have updated the original question with the rule they put in. Yes there are additional .htaccess in the /joomlasite subdirectories.

Comment: "Folders" is a Windows-ism that is incorrectly applied to "directories" and is not the same thing. You are speaking of directories, not folders.

Comment: @Rob It is fine to use the term "folders" when talking about directories.  Directories are a type of folder.   See SuperUser's [Directory vs. Folder](https://superuser.com/questions/169457/directory-vs-folder)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It is fine in that people know what you mean and I said as much. However, technically, it is incorrect as I pointed out and your link also states. If one wants to ask questions about the computer science field, one needs to use the correct terminology and not marketing terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe just sounds like a standard HTTP to HTTPS (and non-www to www) redirect, so it's not clear why the webhost's directives failed in the way you suggest.

However, since you would expect each `/joomlasite` to have its own `.htaccess` file that also contains mod_rewrite directives then this could well complicate matters. Although, if anything, you would expect these subdirectories to not redirect at all. (See below.)

To redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www then try the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

This also assumes the SSL cert is installed on your server and you are not using an SSL front-end proxy to manage your SSL.

Note that this is a 302 temporary redirect. Only change it to a 301 permanent redirect when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

---

**UPDATE:** If you wanted a more generic solution that doesn't involve hardcoding the domain then you can do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This is very similar to the above, except with an additional `RewriteCond` directive, which is required in order to capture the domain apex from the `Host` header.

A generic solution isn't necessarily the "best solution". (Although it might be.) In the infinite world of varying server configs, hardcoding the domain name is often going to be the most reliable solution.

---

However, this may not do anything for the subdirectories that contain their own `.htaccess` files (if these files also contain mod_rewrite directives). If this is the case then you will either need to repeat the above directives in each subdirectory's `.htaccess` file, or enable mod_rewrite inheritance by either placing the following directive in each subdirectory's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

Or, on Apache 2.4.8+, you can instead include the following directive in just the *root* `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

But whether the mod_rewrite inheritance is successful without modifying existing directives is dependent on what other directives you have in the parent `.htaccess` file.

mod_rewrite inheritance is not trivial. Directives are literally copied in-place. So, if you have per-directory directives that are dependent on the relative file-path then these can break. (This is primarily why I have used `REQUEST_URI` in the directive above, rather than capturing the URL-path from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.) So, the easiest solution - without knowing more about your system - may be to simply copy the redirect directives (above) into each sub `.htaccess` file.

---

**UPDATE:**

> This is the rule they put in:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

If these directives were used in the `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site and mod_rewrite inheritance was also enabled (as described above), then this would indeed exhibit the behaviour you were seeing, ie. everything in `/joomlasite` is redirected to the root. eg. `http://www.example.com/joomlasite/foo` would get redirected to `https://www.example.com/foo` in the root - the `/joomlasite` directory is effectively "lost".

This is because the inherited directives are copied in-place (as mentioned above). If these directives are run in the context of the `.htaccess` file in the `/joomlasite` subdirectory then the URL-path captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (and later used in the `$1` backreference) would be `foo`, not `joomlasite/foo`, because the directory-prefix (of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is first removed from the URL-path. This then results in a *substitution* of the form `https://www.example.com/foo`.

However, the directives I posted earlier, that use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `$1`, get around this issue since `REQUEST_URI` always contains the full URL-path of the request.

Comment: I've updated my answer explaining why this might have failed with the original code the webhost provided (which has since been added to the question). Have you tried my code suggestion? This should be exempt from this unwanted behaviour. This also canonicalises the www part of the URL, which the webhost's code did not (unless this was implemented as another rule?).

Comment: Yes I tried your suggestion thanks! However it gave me a redirect loop. Presuming this is some sort of server configuration issue that stopped it working. The one in my answer below however does work. However I am unclear why this works.

Comment: OMG! I've just noticed a typo in my answer/code (now corrected). The first `RewriteRule` should have read `RewriteCond`! Ooops, sorry! (The second `RewriteRule` would have indeed resulted in an unconditional redirect loop!)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a generic solution that doesn't require a hardcoded domain.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the thorough explanation @MrWhite. I have one question. When I tried to implement your code I got an infinite redirect loop. I looked at alternatives and this one below worked. Just curious why the two would differ? Is there some sort of server config that would cause it?

```
RewriteEngine On


# Redirect HTTP with www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
# Redirect HTTPS without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: If you excuse the typo that I had in my code suggestion/answer (now corrected!) then this is actually _exactly_ the same (just more convoluted). In fact, the code you posted here isn't strictly correct as you shouldn't be using the `NC` flag on the negated _CondPatterns_ (ie. `!^www\. [NC]`), only on the first rule block - although that makes no difference to the outcome for _normal_ requests.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give your solution a try again as it is simpler than the alternative I found here. Is there any advantage / disadvantage of writing the domain in against using HTTP_HOST for the RewriteRule?

Comment: The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header, ie. whatever hostname the user has used on the request (eg. www or non-www). Hardcoding the domain and using `HTTP_HOST` are not necessarily the same thing. In the code example in my answer, you will need to hardcode the domain, otherwise you will get a redirect loop when specifiying the bare domain. With the enormous variety of server configs, hardcoding the domain is always going to be the most reliable. However, I'll update my answer to include a generic solution that doesn't require a hardcoded domain.